# PHP - Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: php, file-get-contents

For 2 days I'm having trouble with my PHP script on my server. I've changed nothing and suddenly it didn't work anymore.

Here is the code:

```
$query = http_build_query($data);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",     
        'method'  => "POST",
        'content' => $query,
    ),
);
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n",'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),));
$contexts = stream_context_create($opts);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $contexts, -1, 40000);
```

I'm getting these error messages:

> Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded in
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://mobile.dsbcontrol.de): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server
> Error in

But when I try the script locally it works perfectly.

Comment: I also ran into this issue. It looks like it was caused by upgrading packages. I added: $http['header'] = 'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n"; which suppresses the notice.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are passing `$contexts` to `file_get_contents()` and that only contains the `User-Agent` header in the `$opts` array.  All other headers and options are in the `$options` array which you add in to `$context` but aren't using.  Try:

```
$query = http_build_query($data);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n".
                    "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n",
        'method'  => "POST",
        'content' => $query,
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);
```

Comment: the first error is gone thanks but im still having trouble with warning.

Answer (score 0):

While the existing answers did not work for me, I managed to solve the problem like this:

[The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) says `params` must be an associative array in the format `$arr['parameter'] = $value`. Refer to context parameters for a listing of standard stream parameters.

```
    $header = array(
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length: ".strlen($postdata)
        );


    $packet['method'] = "POST";
    $packet['header'] = implode("\r\n", $header);
    $packet['content'] = $postdata;

    $transmit_data = array('http' => $packet);
    $context = stream_context_create($transmit_data);
```

Comment: In my case I had specified content-type but there was no space that's why PHP engine could not find it. Added a space between another option and content-type and it worked. `$this->options= ['http' => [
                'header' => 'Authorization:' . md5($ftpUserKey) . ' Content-type: application/json',
                'method' => $method,
                'content' => json_encode($this->params),]];`

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this

```
$url = '';

$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header' => 'Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => http_build_query($dataQuery)
            )
        ))), true);
```