# Form Submitting without captcha

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement google captcha v2 on a website that gets a lot of spam mail. The captcha is showing and working, but the form can be submitted without pressing the captcha. I had a look for similar questions but couldn't find any that would help me.

It is google's captcha V2

Form:

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" onsubmit="return FrontPage_Form1_Validator(this)" language="JavaScript" name="FrontPage_Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" class="col-md-13 col-xs-12 name" name='name' placeholder='Name *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-13 col-xs-12 Email" name='Email' placeholder='Email *'/>
<input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='Subject' placeholder='Subject'/>
<textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='Message' placeholder='Message *'></textarea>
<br>

<div class="captcha_wrapper col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld-ryQUAAAAAJSKzJubdxYjigpiTfhk11e1P7o9">
    </div>

</div>
```

mailer.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
}
} 
else {

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

    $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";

} 
}

//captcha section

$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];


$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

$data = array(
    'secret' => '6Ld-ryQUAAAAALpIkTPN82doQhCFmiWrC14_UbYk',
    'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

//end of captcha section

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

if ($forward == 1) {
header ("Location:$location"); 
}
else {
include("index.html");
header( 'Location: ' ) ;
}
```

`

Thank you. Any help is appreciated

I feel like I need to put the captcha code inside in if(isset())

Comment: Check your `$captcha_success` value.

Comment: I had this 

 if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
  echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
 } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
  echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
 }

but it would always return "You are a bot" AND then still send an email

Answer (score 0):

Print the $captcha_success values in order to check what's inside $captcha_success and understand how to manage the response. Then you can redirect the navigation properly.

> var_dump($captcha_success); // to dump the values to web page
>   error_log(print_r($captcha_success, true),0); // to dump to the php
>   apache error_log

Comment: I commented out that code and it's still http error :/  but only on /mailer.php

Comment: If you have error 500, you have to check the php apache error log file. If you can't check the error log, rollback the latest changes you have made and dump the $_POST data in order to check what the form is sending to server: try var_dump($_POST); (if you are using POST method) before "//captcha section" line

Comment: Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in C:\xxamp\htdocs\super\mailer.php on line 50
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["challenge_ts"]=> string(20) "2017-06-09T07:21:45Z" ["hostname"]=> string(9) "localhost" }

Comment: line 50 is $url

Comment: Looks like the captcha is working. Now i'm just having this error file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Ok. For the Notice, you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150489/8130862

Comment: The error is no longer showing. The form still submits without the captcha though

Comment: We need to see the whole script. Your script seems not to check $captcha_success. There was an IF statement about the variable this morning. Check out this demo https://www.kaplankomputing.com/blog/tutorials/recaptcha-php-demo-tutorial/ You need to do something like this:     if ($captcha_success->success==false) { echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>"; } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) { echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";}